# python -kivy GStreamer Error

Tags: kivy, raspberry-pi3

I can't play video on kivy on the raspberry pi 3, Its

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-12-19_8.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [VideoGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.4.4.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: gstplayer
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file /media/pi/michaeldestiny/test.png
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture /media/pi/michaeldestiny/test.mp4
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] GStreamer encountered a general supporting library error.
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] GStreamer encountered a general supporting library error.
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
```

Don't know what the supporting library error is for. And I also notice that its trying to load and 'Image' in

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file /media/pi/michaeldestiny/test.png
```

That file doesn't exist, and also it then tries to read the the actually video file but as an 'Image'

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture /media/pi/michaeldestiny/test.mp4
```

Can someone pls direct me to the right direction

This is the code.......

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.clock import Clock
from webserver.models import *


LabelBase.register(name='Brush', fn_regular='Lobster_1.3.ttf')
class Billboard(App):


    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_db, 1)

    def text_screen(self, info):
        if info.source:
            try:
                data = Data.get(name=info.source)
                self.root.ids.text_log.text= data.content
            except:
                pass
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current='Text'

    def image_screen(self,info):
        if info.source:
            self.root.ids.s_image.source = info.source
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current='Image'

    def video_screen(self,info):
        if info.source:
            self.root.ids.s_video.source =info.source
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current='Video'


    def check_db(self,nap):
        screens = ['Text','Image','Video']
        try:
            info = Info.get(Info.id ==1)
        except:
            info = None
        if info:
            if info.screen == 'Text':
                self.text_screen(info)
            if info.screen == 'Image':
                self.image_screen(info)
            if info.screen == 'Video':
                self.video_screen(info)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Billboard().run()
```

The source is update from a database, and the database is update through a web app

Comment: what is the actual code that you wrote for achieving your purpose?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: did you figure this out ? I have the same issue :(